# Evento 'click' con input no da el resultado esperado

Tags: javascript, html, botón, input

estoy practicando Javascript y html y cuando quiero hacer un input del tipo "number" con dos variables(numeros) a la hora de usar javascript no me da el resultado correcto y me lanza: "NaN"
Utilizo boostrap para los botones y fondo, el boton sumar tendría que arrojar el resultado de los dos numeros en el input sumados.
El boton restar no hace nada por ahora.

```js
const spanResultadoCuenta = document.getElementById('spanResultado')
var numUno = document.getElementById('num_uno').value;
var numDos = document.getElementById('num_dos').value;
const btnSumar = document.getElementById('sumar');
var resultado = 0;

btnSumar.addEventListener('click', () => {

    
spanResultadoCuenta.textContent = Number(numUno)+Number(numDos);



} )
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Botones sumadores y restadores</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    
    <div class="container py-5 bg-warning text-center">
         <label for="num_uno" id="num_uno">Numero Uno</label>
        <input type="number">
        <label for="num_dos" id="num_dos">Numero Dos</label>
        <input type="number">

        <button class="btn btn-info" id="sumar">
            Sumar
        </button>
        <button class="btn btn-danger" id="restar">
            Restar
        </button>
        <h4 class="my-5">Resultado: <span id=spanResultado>0</span></h4>

        <script src="scriptboton.js"></script>

    </div>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tienes dos problemas:

1. Estás usando el id para la `etiqueta` (`label`), tienes que usarlo
   en el `input`.
2. Cuando haces `var numUno = document.getElementById('num_uno').value;` estas guardando en `numUno` el valor de tu elemento `input` con el que se cargó la página, no con el valor actual que corresponde al de cada vez que el usuario lo cambia, te recomiendo guardar la referencia al elemento, así: `var numUno = document.getElementById('num_uno')` y luego puedes acceder al valor actual del elemento de tipo `input` haciendo `numUno.val`.

Con estas correcciones te quedaría algo así:

```js
const spanResultadoCuenta = document.getElementById('spanResultado')
var numUno = document.getElementById('num_uno');
var numDos = document.getElementById('num_dos');
const btnSumar = document.getElementById('sumar');
var resultado = 0;

btnSumar.addEventListener('click', () => {


  spanResultadoCuenta.textContent = Number(numUno.value) + Number(numDos.value);



})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Botones sumadores y restadores</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container py-5 bg-warning text-center">
    <label for="num_uno">Numero Uno</label>
    <input type="number" id="num_uno">
    <label for="num_dos">Numero Dos</label>
    <input type="number" id="num_dos">

    <button class="btn btn-info" id="sumar">
            Sumar
        </button>
    <button class="btn btn-danger" id="restar">
            Restar
        </button>
    <h4 class="my-5">Resultado: <span id=spanResultado>0</span></h4>

    <script src="scriptboton.js"></script>

  </div>



</body>

</html>
```

Entiendo que el código puede mejorarse, pero quiero que comprendas porqué no estás obteniendo el comportamiento esperado.

Comment: Muchas gracias, es correcto y ahora entiendo el comportamiento.

Answer (score 0):

El boton restar no te hace nada, porque deberias crear otra función para tal fin. Algo que estuve leyendo y aplicaré en mis futuros códigos es mantener el archivo js en el head, solo hay que usar defer, para diferir la carga js después de que cargue el html.

```js
const spanResultadoCuenta = document.getElementById('spanResultado')
var numUno = document.getElementById('num_uno');
var numDos = document.getElementById('num_dos');
const btnSumar = document.getElementById('sumar');
const btnRestar = document.getElementById('restar');
const btnMultiplicar = document.getElementById('multiplicar');
const btnDividir = document.getElementById('dividir');
var resultado = 0;

btnSumar.addEventListener('click', () => {

  spanResultadoCuenta.textContent = Number(numUno.value) + Number(numDos.value);

})
btnRestar.addEventListener('click', () => {

  spanResultadoCuenta.textContent = Number(numUno.value) - Number(numDos.value);

})
btnMultiplicar.addEventListener('click', () => {

  spanResultadoCuenta.textContent = Number(numUno.value) * Number(numDos.value);

})
btnDividir.addEventListener('click', () => {

  spanResultadoCuenta.textContent = Number(numUno.value) / Number(numDos.value);

})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Botones sumadores y restadores</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
    integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script defer src="archivo.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container py-5 bg-warning text-center">
    <label for="num_uno">Numero Uno</label>
    <input type="number" id="num_uno">
    <label for="num_dos">Numero Dos</label>
    <input type="number" id="num_dos">

    <button class="btn btn-info" id="sumar">
      Sumar +
    </button>
    <button class="btn btn-danger" id="restar">
      Restar -
    </button>
    <button class="btn btn-info" id="dividir">
      Dividir /
    </button>
    <button class="btn btn-danger" id="multiplicar">
      Multiplicar x
    </button>
    <h4 class="my-5">Resultado: <span id=spanResultado>0</span></h4>


  </div>



</body>

</html>
```